# Core Location StartMonitoring Background Working

Tags: swift, core-location, beacon

I can scan beacons when app working foreground but cannot work app in background. I added "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" in İnfo.plist and background modes "Location Updates"

```
func initScanBeacon() {

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways {

      if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
        if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
          startScanning()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func startScanning() {
    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "xxxxx")!
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 0, minor: 0, identifier: "xxxxx")

    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beacons.count > 0 {
      //print
    } else {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, iOS apps won't continue to range beacons for more than a few seconds after shifting to the background.  This is true even if you obtain "always" location usage permission form the user and set `locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true`.

There are a number of tricks you can do to extend background ranging to more than a few seconds.  For specifics, please see my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049591/1461050)